# How to close element outside click of that element with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Here I am trying to close element out click of that element but it take also click on it and close when I am trying to type something in textbox.

So when I click on search icon that search box will open and I don't wont to close that section when I am click that search box to type something.

I want to close that search **.search-form** when I click out side the **.search-wrap**.

I try many thing searching from stack-overflow, but I am not getting proper solution.

```js
jQuery('.search-wrap-icon').on('click', function(e){
    jQuery(this).parent('.search-wrap').addClass('search-box-open');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (jQuery(e.target).is(".search-wrap, .search-form") === false) {
      jQuery(".search-wrap").removeClass("search-box-open");
    }
  });
```

```css
.search-form {
    position: absolute;
    left: -21px;
    top: -13px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.search-box-open .search-form {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.search-form input {
    width: 243px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ebf1f7;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

.search-form button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="search-wrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="search-wrap-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <div class="search-form">
        <form method="get" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Job type search">
            <button tabindex="0" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="submit">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwZ3n.png">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a working example of what you are trying to do. https://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your e.target is going to be your input whenever you click on the search box. Instead, you can check if the element is the search wrapper itself, or if it is a child of the search wrapper with `.parents()`

Here's the relevant line:

```
if(!(jQuery(e.target).hasClass("search-wrap") || jQuery(e.target).parents(".search-wrap").length > 0))
```

---

And here's the snippet:

```js
jQuery('.search-wrap-icon').on('click', function(e){
    jQuery(this).parent('.search-wrap').addClass('search-box-open');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if(!(jQuery(e.target).hasClass("search-wrap") || jQuery(e.target).parents(".search-wrap").length > 0))
      jQuery(".search-wrap").removeClass("search-box-open");
  });
```

```css
.search-form {
    position: absolute;
    left: -21px;
    top: -13px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.search-box-open .search-form {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.search-form input {
    width: 243px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ebf1f7;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

.search-form button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="search-wrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="search-wrap-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <div class="search-form">
        <form method="get" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Job type search">
            <button tabindex="0" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="submit">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwZ3n.png">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but when i click on search icon **.search-form** it all hide.

Comment: Ya but i need that button as well to search on that button click , so is there any other way ?

Comment: Oh actually, that's submitting the form. You're seeing it disappear because it's submitting the form and going to another page. It's in an iframe here, so you just see a new blank page.